# How to add Entities from Multiple Schema to a single edmx model diagram in the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two database schema  in MYSQL, I created two edmx models using the Entity framework. However what I need is to add entities from both the schema into one edmx diagram.

The problem is that an edmx model is created for a single schema

Please advice.

Comment: What happened when you tried ?

Comment: You cannot add entities from other schema as  an edmx model is created for a single schema